# One to one left join across two tables

Tags: postgresql

So.. This is the query I have:

```
WITH cat AS (
    SELECT day, domain
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY day, domain
), dog AS (
    SELECT day, domain, SUM(count)
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY day, domain
)
SELECT c.domain,
    COALESCE(SUM(d.count),0) AS count
FROM cat c
LEFT JOIN dog d
    ON c.domain = d.domain
    AND c.day <= d.day
GROUP BY c.domain;
```

Here's what the "cat" returns:

```
    day     |  domain 
------------+-----------
 2015-10-01 | nba.com 
 2015-10-02 | nba.com
```

And here's what the "dog" returns:

```
    day     | domain     | count 
------------+----------------+--------
 2015-10-03 | nba.com    |   2
```

And here is what the full query returns:

```
domain     | count 
------------+-------
nba.com    |   4
```

Count is  4 because the LEFT JOIN satisfies both of the rows in "cat". However, I want the left join only being applied ONCE.. (i.e. have a count of 2 rather than 4). That is the "dog" count of 2 be only applied ONCE (if it is ever satisfied).. and not more than that. Is this possible? I hope I made sense here

Comment: So what should the final result look like?

Comment: domain:
nba.com

count:
2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear.

If you want to find the first row from `dog`:

```
WITH cat AS (
    SELECT day, domain
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY day, domain
), dog AS (
    SELECT day, domain, SUM(count) count
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY day, domain
)
SELECT DISTINCT on (c.domain) c.domain,
    COALESCE(d.count, 0) AS count
FROM cat c
LEFT JOIN dog d
    ON c.domain = d.domain
    AND c.day <= d.day
ORDER BY c.domain, c.day, d.day;
```

If you want to sum all rows from `dog` (which meet the conditions):

```
WITH cat AS (
    SELECT day, domain
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY day, domain
), dog AS (
    SELECT day, domain, SUM(count) count
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY day, domain
), cat_and_dogs as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(c.domain, d.day) c.domain, d.count
    FROM cat c
    LEFT JOIN dog d
        ON c.domain = d.domain
        AND c.day <= d.day
)
SELECT domain,
    COALESCE(sum(count), 0) AS count
FROM cat_and_dogs
GROUP BY domain;
```

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear and thankyou for the answer. However, what I'm trying to do is have the "dog" portion only have the "LEFT JOIN" portion only be satisfied for the  " 2015-10-02" cat entry.. and NOT the " 2015-10-01" cat entry.. Thus giving me a count of "2"

Comment: That's ok, then the second variant should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I agree with @klin that question is not clear. If you don NOT want to apply `LEFT JOIN` each times for all domain entries from `cat` result, `domain` column should be unique, so you will NOT hit **`SUM(count)`** in `dog` result twice.

You can use `count` column just in `cat` table to simply your query, but if you have a reason to keep them separate, it might be a good idea to rely on some other unique column to join on.

```
WITH cat(day,domain) AS (
  VALUES
  ('2015-10-01'::DATE,'nba.com'),
  ('2015-10-02'::DATE,'nba.com')
),dog(day,domain,count) AS (
  VALUES
  ('2015-10-03'::DATE, 'nba.com', 1),
  ('2015-10-03'::DATE, 'nba.com', 1)
),dog_data AS (
    SELECT day, domain, SUM(count) count
    FROM dog
    GROUP BY day, domain
), result_to_normilize AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(c.domain,c.day) c.domain,c.day,
      COALESCE(SUM(d.count),0) AS count
    FROM cat c
      LEFT JOIN dog_data d
        ON c.domain = d.domain
           AND c.day <= d.day
    GROUP BY c.domain,c.day
    -- | domain  |    day     | count
    -- | nba.com | 2015-10-01 | 2
    -- | nba.com | 2015-10-02 | 2
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.domain) r.domain, r.count
FROM result_to_normilize r;
  -- | domain  | count
  -- | nba.com | 2
```